# Bat to count number of time a tag appears in an XML file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I want to create a batch on windows 10 which will count the number of times a particular tag appears in an XML file.
Below is the code I have found and tried.  It is supposed to put the value between a set of tags in another file but this is not working in my case:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.xml) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%X in (^"^
% Do NOT remove this line %
^") do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("!line:>=%%~X!") do (
      if /I "!field!" equ "<LineCde" for /F "delims=<" %%c in ("%%b") do echo %%c >> file2.txt
      set "field=%%b"
   )
)
Pause
```

My XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document><Mouvement>
<Commande>
    <RefCommande>xxx</RefCommande>
    <SystemRefCde>xx</SystemRefCde>
    <StatusCommande>
      <CodeStatusOpCommande>xxx</CodeStatusOpCommande>
      <DateStatusOpCommande>04/09/2017</DateStatusOpCommande>
      <TimeStatusOpCommande>09:13:58</TimeStatusOpCommande>
    </StatusCommande>
    <LineCde>
      <RefLineCde>xxx</RefLineCde>
      <SystemRefLigneCde>32R</SystemRefLigneCde>
      <TimeHour>
        <TypeDate>xxx</TypeDate>
        <ValueDate>04/09/2017</ValueDate>
        <TimeDate>00:00:00</TimeDate>
      </TimeHour>
    </LineCde>
</Commande>
</Mouvement></Document>
```

Can anyone help me with this?  The code did work in windows 7.  Thanks

With for:

```
findstr /ip /D:"\Vi\Defect+Evo\Traduction\testB" 

*.xml >> log-it.txt
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" log-it.txt | find /C "/LineCde""

for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
del /Q log-it.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do a search for `xxx` for instance in the `test.xml` file and echo the number of times found.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" test.xml | find /C "xxx""

for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

Using the same script as above, but we search all `xml` files in the directory for the string, then pipe them all to a logfile and echo the total of the logfile.

```
@echo off
findstr /ip /c:"xxx" *.xml >> log-it.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" log-it.txt | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
del /Q log-it.txt
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment.

```
findstr /ip /d:\Vi\Defect+Evo\Trad\testB\te *.xml
```

will never work. you cannot remove the `c:` this is not a path, this is the string to search for.

```
@echo off
findstr /ip /c:"/LineCde" D:\Vi\Defect+Evo\Traduction\testB\*.xml >> log-it.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" log-it.txt | find /C "/LineCde""

for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
del /Q log-it.txt
```

to Break it down a bit so you get what is happening:

```
findstr /ip /c:"/LineCde" D:\Vi\Defect+Evo\Traduction\testB\*.xml >> log-it.txt
    #Findstr searches for a string
    # /i makes the search non-case sensitive. 
    # /p Skip files with non-printable characters.
    # /c: specifies the string to find. in this case "/LineCde"
    # then we specify where to search (D:\...) and what to search (*.xml)
    # >> we pipe it to a log file. (log-it.txt)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    # enable Delayed expansion
set "string=findstr /R /N "^^" log-it.txt | find /C "/LineCde""
    # Now we do the same, we read from the logfile as we wrote each of the XML entries and create them in the logfile, we just count all the entries together.
for /f %%a in ('!string!') do set count=%%a
    # once we found each line number, we set it as a variable
echo %count%
    # we print that variable to screen
del /Q log-it.txt
    # Now we delete the file because we do not need it and next time we will create a new file.
```

Comment: It works, thank you.  I have another question though: what if I want to loop in a folder and go through each XML to do the counting?  How can we do this?

Comment: @tabby Cool. If you feel it solved the initial issue, please mark as correct answer. I will edit the question in a few minutes to add and answer to your second question.

Comment: Yes I will mark it as correct answer.  However, can you still edit the question and answer after this?

Comment: Yes. I can edit at anytime. Busy editing it now in my script before I post.

Comment: No it does not work.  It writes only the file location in the log file but does not do any count.

Comment: findstr /ip /d:\Vi\Defect+Evo\Trad\testB\te *.xml >> log-it.txt   This is the 2nd line of your code.  Now nothing is being written in the log file.

Comment: something is completely wrong with your code. can you post a sample of your original xml and what string you are searching for?

Comment: Yes my XML are in D

Comment: ok, and the string you want to search for in the xml is `LineCde`?

Comment: Yes LineCde in the XML

Comment: see last edit. I will also add some comments so it makes sense.

Comment: Cool! I am editing the answer so you can see what happens exactly. check back in a minute or so

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner?

```
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN ('find /c test.xml "<LigneCde>" /i') DO echo %%i
```